Can I prove $G_s=H$ if $H$ is normal in $G$, where $S=G/H$
If $H$ is normal in $G$, where $S=G/H$,
and $G$ acts on $S$, can I prove $G_s=H$ for any $s$ in $S$?
(where $G_s$ is the stablizer of $s$)
My try, if action is left multiply by $g$,
to stablize $s=aH$, if $h \in H$, $haH=hHa=Ha=aH$ (using $aH=Ha$ since $H$ is normal),
so $H \subset G_s$, also if $gaH=aH$ $\implies$
$gHa=aH$ $\implies$ $gH=aHa^{-1}=H$, so $g \in H$, $G_s \subset H$,
so $H=G_s$
if action is right multiply by $g$, result is similar, $G_s=H$ for any $s$ in $S$.
if action is conjugate, step $H \subset G_s$ is similar, but if $gaHg^{-1}=aH$ $\implies$ $gaH=aHg$ $\implies$ $gaH=agH$ (using $gH=Hg)$, then it seemed only need $ga=ag$, so I can't conclude $G_s \subset H$.
Currently I can only think 3 actions: left multiply, right multiply, conjugate.
Can I prove this, $G_s=H$ for any $s$ in $S$ for arbitray action?
Edit: Mark pointed out even for trivial action this is false.
I can prove action of left multiply, right multiply is true,
but cannot prove action of conjugate.

No way this is true for any action. For example, what about the trivial action $g.x=x$ for any $g\in G, x\in S$? Then the stabilizer of any element is the whole $G$.

After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.

$G$ acts by left multiplication on the left quotient (set, in general) $G/H$, and $G_{aH}=$ $aHa^{-1}$ (see below). So, if $H$ is normal, then $G_{aH}=H$ for every $a\in G$.
Proof.
\begin{alignat}{1}
G_{aH} &= \{g\in G\mid gaH=aH\} \\
&= \{g\in G\mid a^{-1}gaH=H\} \\
&\stackrel{g':=a^{-1}ga}{=} \{ag'a^{-1}\in G\mid g'H=H\} \\
&= a\{g'\in G\mid g'H=H\}a^{-1} \\
&= a\{g'\in G\mid g'\in H\}a^{-1} \\
&= aHa^{-1} \\
\end{alignat}

Let $s=gH$. We have
$$\begin{array}{rll}
x\in G_{s}&\iff xgH=gH&\text{(definition)}\\
&\iff g^{-1}xg\in H&\text{(normality)}\\
&\iff x\in gHg^{-1}&\text{(conjugation)}\\
&\iff x\in H&\text{(normality)}\\
\end{array}$$
